# Watching for change in properties values

Tags: objective-c, key-value-observing, key-value-coding

I have a class (Model) which has several properties. I have a save button(in Controller), which saves this model, by writing into disk. After saving a model, if any of the properties are modified (by calling setters) I have to save the model again. Hence I wish to be notified if any properties are modified. Is this similar to Key Value Observing? Anyhow, how can I achieve this? I'm very new to this topic. Please explain me clearly.

Comment: This is **exactly** what Key-Value Observing is for. I'd recommend reading [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving).

Comment: You need key value observing. Search the internet for Key Value Observing. There are good documents provided by Apple.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. But how do I observe for any changes in a model. As in, Any property is set, then I wish to be notified, without even knowing what the properties can be.